# Data Format in Keras Model

Tags: keras, dataformat

I'm using a Convolutional Network, and I wonder which `data_format` is being used in my code? Because from this page: [Convolutional Layers](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/)

In the Conv2D layer section, it says input shape can assume two different forms depending on the `data_format` (`"channels_first"` or `"channels_last"`). I assume on of them is the default option?

And what command should I add to my code to change between those two formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, just found the answer, here:

[Answer](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/31/keras-conv2d-and-convolutional-layers/)

So, it uses the `"channels_last"` if using TensorFlow backend to keras and `"channels_first"` if using Theano backend.